# ddd - How to properly identify Value Objects?

Tags: domain-driven-design, value-objects

I am modeling my entities, and have been struggling with this for a long time. Here is my `Person` Entity:

```
Person
    ID
    Name
    Email
    Password
    City
    Phone
    Biography
    Rating
    Description
```

I have tried to divide these properties into Value Objects, but so far I only have been able to convert them to VOs (for example, City is a VO made with a city name, and country name).

Should I try to create larger VOs, by putting together, for example, `Email` and `Password` into a `Credentials` VO ? Am I going too deep in the separation into VOs ?

Any help is greatly appreciated

[EDIT]

After some discussion, it appears that the best solution is to keep every property in it's own VO, except for Email and Password that should be grouped in a "Credentials" VO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value objects are things who's values uniquely identify them I.e. equality is done by the values, rather than an explicit property (like ID) to provide uniqueness. Two value objects are equal if all their fields are equal

When trying to identify them, follow the language the domain experts use. What words do they use when discussing People? Do they refer to credentials, or email and password?

Also look to identify groups of properties that are always used together. For example, if Password is always used alongside Email it makes sense to group them in a Credentials object, as you can then push behaviour there (i.e. Credentials.Validate())

[UPDATE]

All of the following properties are candidates for value objects *depending on the invariants you need to enforce*

**Name**

- are there min / max values for names?
- are there any characters not allowed?

**Email**

- is it a valid email address
- can two people have the same email address?

**Password**

- min / max length?
- required characters?
- invalid characters?

**Phone**

- is it a valid phone number?
- how do you deal with international dialing codes?

**Rating**

- is there a min and max value allowed for a rating?
- how is it calculated? (is it calculated?)

**Description**

**Biography**

**City**

etc....

If you create Value Objects for the above concepts instead of using primitive values such as int or string, you can encapsulate your business rules inside the value objects.

You might want to combine Email and Password into a Credentials Value Object if you use the two things cohesively. i.e. login with credentials etc... You can still access Credentials.Email if you need to use the Email outside of the Credentials object.

Comment: The problem is, that I'm kind of making my teeth onto DDD with this project, and I am working solo, so I am the domain expert as well as the developer, and that makes it kind of hard to use the Ubiquitous Language

Comment: Try the second approach then - things that are used together often

Comment: The problem is that some fields could be used without other ones. To take your example, Email could be used without Password, to be displayed on a profile page for example, and that is why I'm struggling with this.

Comment: Focus on the behaviour not the data. Write down all the use cases you will be supporting and see where this takes you

Comment: I am building the webapp brick by brick, so far I have one complete Use Case that is "A person can view another person's profile". All the data listed on my question is the data that should be shown in this use case

Comment: Some good stuff here: https://lostechies.com/joeocampo/2007/04/23/a-discussion-on-domain-driven-design-value-objects/

Comment: Already took a look at this but I still can't make the logical connections to help me create my value objects.. I mean Email + Password is a Credential VO, but Email + Name is a VO too I think.. What about City and Phone ? They can be both separate VOs, or combined in a "ProfileData" VO... Am I trying to go too deep ?

Comment: I dont like ProfileData, just sounds like a bag of properties, which is what you currently have. Email + Name - what VO is that? I've updated my answer with some additional thoughts. In general, I wouldnt worry too much about it at the beginning, I'd let the code reflect concepts as they emerge

Comment: I just saw your updated answer. The problem is I want to enforce as many invariants as possible. For example: Name must be à VO because it contains a first, middle and last name. City because it contains the country code too, etc. I think I am still not able to separate properties in VOs, even with my specific use case

Comment: I don't understand - why can you not just do what you describe?

Comment: I am trying to describe my Person Entity, based on my use case (the only for now) "A person can view another one's profile". The properties in my Question are the one that are shown on the output of the use case, and I am trying to regroup them into VOs so the Person Entity isn't just a big pile of properties

Comment: So just do that... Have a City value object and a Name value object etc that are properties of the Person

Comment: So everything that I listed is a VO then, except the Email + Password that I really see as Credentials (even if Email can be shown on profile), right ?

Comment: I wasnt sure about Description and Biography but the other ones, yes, if they have business rules to enforce then make them VOs, and yes, Credentials sounds good too. :)

Comment: Description and Biography have their own business rules ( minimum 250 chars for biography, and max 250 for description).

Comment: Ok, cool so they're VOs too. Looks like you've got a few new classes to create :)

Answer (score 1):

What you have there looks suspiciously as a data structure (CRUD). In proper DDD you start with the business case like "Create Person" and then you find out the **model representing** the Person **concept**.

The model is defined by a group of components and business rules. Your components are usually VOs , because they are models representing minor concepts that can be expressed as a simple or composite value with no explicit identity and they encapsulate specific business constraints. For example, the `Email` VO makes sure you have a valid email value.

You should let the domain tells you if it makes sense to create bigger VO; usually you start with a VO and you *discover* it's made up from other VOs. Generally, we go top to down. You can [see here](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2016/07/14/DDD-Aggregate-Decoded-2) a modelling example.

It's hard when you don't have a domain expert but you can still try to think in business cases and identify whatever specific model for each case. If you end up with mainly simple structures and some data validation rules, perhaps you have a simple enough domain to just use a CRUD approach.

Comment: In the linked account modeling example, how the invariant that a debit may not exceed the account balance would be implemented? Would you rely on the read model for this and thus make it eventually consistent? I guess that some kind of limit on the amounts would have to be put in place so that we do not have to compensate insanely high amounts of money.

Comment: @plalx What you say is part of a domain service, not the Transfer aggregate. Transfer doesn't know about AccountBalance. The business rule can allow a higher amount => you get a nice overdraft fee or prevent that. But my example was focused on aggregate only, not on the entire business case.

Comment: What I'm saying is that there is no way to prevent an overdraft transactionnaly since Transfer is the only aggregate at play and has no notion of balances. Imagine that you maxed account transfer amounts to 1000$ per day to avoid extremely high overdrafts. How would you deal about a scenario that someone exploits race conditions by performing multiple concurrent transfer requests and therefore cumulatively exceed the 1000$ per day? I think this is a model banks must follow because of their distributed nature, but leaving the invariants exposed is much more complex than preventing an overdraft.

Comment: You can remove CQRS and you still have the same problem. And what you're saying it's basically a scripted attack (you can't do that stuff manually), which is a different problem. The only solution is to execute _all_ transactions synchronously which means very low performance. But a bank doesn't have a problem with a couple of simultaneous transactions. It can issue compensatory actions later if required.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to impose a particular domain model structure, you need to approach domain modeling from the use cases perspective.

> Should I try to create larger VOs, by putting together, for example, Email and Password into a Credentials VO ?

You should do that only if the two tend to be used together. If they don't, leaving them along is just fine.

Note that sometimes it makes sense to extract a single property into its own value object if the number of invariants it needs to support is high enough to justify introducing a new concept. Take a look at [this article](http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/03/07/functional-c-primitive-obsession/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

it is not always clear a concept in your domain is a value object or entity and unfortunately there are no objective attributes you could use to get to know it whether or not a notion is a value object fully it depends on the problem domain, a concept can be an entity in one domain model or a value object in another. most of times a money class is a value object but not all money objects are value object. how you can find out a value object? first of all you should check the notion of identity if it is structurally equal (it means two objects are same if objects values are same, not ids of objects), you can safety replace an instance of class which has same set of attributes. that is good sign this concept is a value object.

a good way of thinking value object is thinking if it is an integer, do you really care if integer 5 is same as 5 you used in other function? definitely not all 5 in your application are same, regardless how they were instantiated. that's make integer essentially a value object, now ask your self the object in your domain is like an integer? if answer is yes then it is a value object. also, value objects are immutable and more light weight as entities.